# Cannot debug my app because of the maximum App ID limit

Tags: ios, xcode

I just finished creating an app and I wanted to test it myself before launching it on AppStore. I installed it yesterday on my iPhone and started using it like a regular user would do. Today I noticed that I get a crash everytime I open the app so I couldn't wait to get home to hook my iPhone to Xcode and see what the problem is.

When I hooked it and ran the app via Xcode I get this

`Your maximum App ID limit has been reached. You may create up to 10 App IDs every 7 days.`

`No profiles for 'com.andreivataselu.Studget' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.andreivataselu.Studget'.`

Some fixes on the internet says to change the bundle identifier. If I do this, it installs another identical application instead of running my current installed application, and by doing this I can't really find the bug in the app so I can fix it.

I also don't get the `No profiles for com.andreivataselu.Studget` error since I've been running the app on my phone via Xcode for over a month and I didn't get any error so far.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this for now is

1. If you can delete one the bundle identifiers then please delete that.
2. You can use the bundle identifier from the rest of the available bundle identifers.
3. After 7 days, you can create the new one.

   Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: Well this is a previous bundle identifier I used in past. This is one of the first apps I've created on Xcode. If I use another bundle identifier I won't be able to find the bug